# String formatting in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, formatting

I can't seem to understand why the following does not work:

```
var content : NSString = ""
let myLabel : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as UILabel
content += String(format:"var %@ = false;", myLabel.text)
```

I get the following error:

> NSString is not identical to 'UInt8'

Answer (score 1):

It's because `NSString` class doesn't support appending string using `+`. It only supports if you use `String`. You can fix that issue by:

```
var content : String = ""
let myLabel : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as UILabel
content += String(format:"var %@ = false;", myLabel.text!)
```

Comment: @JeremyPope: I'm using XCode 6.1.1 In that it's not working now checked in latest beta.

Answer (score 0):

try using String interpolation:

```
content += "var \(myLabel.text) = false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using format, why not use Swift's string interpolation?

```
content += "var \(myLabel.text!) = false;"
```

It doesn’t give you the numeric formatting that is so useful in NSString's format, but you are just inserting a string with no formatting required.

However the use of ! without checking always makes me twitch, so how about something like:

```
if let labelText = myLabel.text {
    content += "var \(labelText) = false;"
}
```